# authentication from two table using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new in laravel, I trying to make custom validation from two tables,

i have table users (contain `id,email, password,job_type`) and
 another table name employee with fields `user_id,admin_type_id`,
  my problem is when I trying to check data  with login user and confirm he is an employee with `job_tybe` =1 in table Employee and conform is type is admin by `admin_type_id` =1 when I make `var_dump($admin)` i get output is  `null` 
I found my problem is password registers in database not password that send from a form
how can I make password is I dental to make login
condition of login is `job_tybe` =1+ `admin_type_id` =1
this is my code:-

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = array(
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'password' => $request->get('password'),

    );
    //check user is employee
    $admin=User::where(['email' => $credentials['email'],'password' =>Hash::make($credentials['password']) ,'deleted'=>1,'status'=>1,'job_type'=>1])->first();

        //get admin type
    $adminType=Employee::where(['id_user' => $admin->id, 'admin_type_id'=>1,'deleted'=>1,'status'=>1])->first();;
    if($adminType !=null)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->route('brand.create');
            exit();
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with("messageError","Invalid Email Or Password");

    }
```

Comment: Why you don't use the same authentication system for both and then use roles/gates to manage access to different things?

Answer (score 0):

To make password use "bcrypt('password')" method.